# Recurly: Detecting if an Invoices has non-subscription charges/adjustment

Tags: recurly

Is there a way to differentiate between a charge created programmatically vs a charge created by a renewing subscription vs a manual charge?

Programmatic way: https://dev.recurly.com/docs/create-a-charge-or-credit

Subscription way: a charge is automatically created by Recurly

Manual way: https://docs.recurly.com/docs/adjustments#section-charging-an-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to differentiate between charge types would be to use a distinct accounting code for each type of charge.  For example:
a charge created programmatically: P-12345
a charge created by a renewing subscription: R-12345
a manual charge: M-12345

Then for example with a list account's adjustments API call, loop through the returned data, filter by the `accounting_code` parameter for strings that contain an `P`, `R` or `M`, and return the details of the specific adjustment of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can get some details on the invoice level by doing

```
$isInvoiceFromSubscription = !is_null($invoice->subscription)
//If true the invoice is from an automatic subscription.
```